# How to print an image field in Views with PHP filter

Tags: views

I'm trying to display an image in Views using the PHP filter. If the value of a boolean field (`field_primum`) is `TRUE`, I want the image to display.

The picture is available in `$row->picture`, but when I use this code:

```
if(isset($row->field_primum)) {
  if ($row->field_primum == "1") {
    print ("<div>$row->picture</div>");
  }
}
```

Only the ID of the image prints. How do I render the image itself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all load the file:

```
$file = file_load($row->picture);
```

Then format it as an image and render:

```
print theme('image', array('path' => $file->uri));
```